# Using ExecuteScript in Apache Nifi not working

Tags: python, apache-nifi, processor

I have the following flow showing in the picture attached. I am receiving 60 flowfiles from another process groups and I want them to pass through a Python script that will get executed using ExecuteScript Processor.

[image]

The issue now is I get no errors but none of the flow files are passed as "in" to even go through a simple script where it simply gets the ingoing flowfile, removes it and then creates a new one with the older flowfile attributes. I have some records in the queue but they are not getting into the Execute Script processor at all.
I am just using this simple to test whether I can successfully run a python script or not. Here is my code :

```
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

flowFile = session.get()
attrMap = flowFile.getAttributes()
session.remove(flowFile)
newflowFile = session.create()
newflowFile = session.putAllAttributes(newflowFile, attrMap)
session.transfer(newflowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Here is also a picture of my configurations. Nothing else have been changed.

[image]

Am I missing anything ?

Edit :
Settings
[image]
Scheduling
[image]

Comment: this script should work. it works for me on nifi 1.9. show the `scheduling` & `settings` tabs parameters.

Comment: @daggett My scheduling and settings tab are set as they are defaulted as . could it be a potential bug in ExecuteScript Processor  with the version I am using ? I am using nifi-1.11.4.

Comment: i just tried your script in v1.11.4. and it works fine. so, something wrong in scheduling or cluster... you have to provide more information on this.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdfne.png

Comment: @daggett I have attached a screenshot of scheduling and setting in my orginal post. under Edit.

Comment: where those files are coming from? maybe they are penalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code deletes the incoming flowfile from the session and then creates an unrelated new flowfile. This is not how the script should operate. The framework detects that the script isn't properly handling the data (the incoming flowfile is not transferred to any relationship), so it doesn't allow it to complete and cause data loss.

You should operate *on* the incoming flowfile(s) and then transfer them to the appropriate relationship. There is more information available in the [Apache NiFi Developer Guide -- Common Processor Patterns](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#common-processor-patterns) and [Matt Burgess' blog](https://funnifi.blogspot.com).

Comment: I have changed my script to be this : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sucitw/python-script-in-NiFi/master/read_update_content.py 
I am still getting the same issue. No incoming FF into the processor nor FF going out.